# Word VBA test if in IDE

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to execute (or not execute) some code while I am in the IDE debugging. And vice versa, avoid some code when the IDE is not open.

This used to work:

```
Public Function InIDE() As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   Debug.Print 1 / 0
   InIDE = (VBA.err = 11)
End Function
```

Now it always returns true, probably due to security changes.

What is a proper way in Word 2010 and 2013 to test if the code is executing with the IDE open?

Comment: did it work? in which version of office?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it did work at one time in 2007 and 2010. I think the change that stopped it from working was an OS or Office patch, but I can tell when. I used to use it in very limited cases but recently I want to use it in a production document and it failed. The original need was to save work I did while debugging. The production code closed the document w/o saving, so if I wasn't careful my bug fixes would go away. In this case I'm using one 'macro' document to build others via code. The 'macro' document should not change when it is used hence the close w/o saving.

Comment: I added VBA tag to widen the audience for this question.